# cannot move to my new page on the ionic side menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Decided to move yo hybrid apps and now I'm stuck on something kind of silly..
Opened a new side menu project in IONIC and wanted to add pages to the side menu.
the problem is when i add the new page to the app.html and ts it's just don't move to the new page and the whole app is just staying on the same page it was before I clicked on the new page. (Side menu still open and close but nothing else..)
Must say that the first 2 pages who came with the template are working well until I choose my new page.

Hope you could help me :)

Here is app.html:

```
  <ion-menu [content]="content">
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<ion-list>
  <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
    {{p.title}}
  </button>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

and my App.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';

import { Page1 } from '../pages/page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../pages/page2/page2';
import { ExternalLinksPage } from '../pages/ExternalLinks/ExternalLinks';



@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

rootPage: any = Page1;

pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

constructor(public platform: Platform) {
 this.initializeApp();

// used for an example of ngFor and navigation
this.pages = [
  { title: 'מסך הבית', component: Page1 },
  { title: 'מתכונים', component: Page2 },
  { title: 'קישורים חיצוניים', component: ExternalLinksPage }
];

}

initializeApp() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
  Splashscreen.hide();
});
}

openPage(page) {
// Reset the content nav to have just this page
// we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You added ExternalLinksPage page to app.module.ts file?

Comment: @PareshGami OMG I ♥ U
thank you so much man! sry for the silly question!
BTW Here in Israel this is Rosh Hashana , celebrating the new Hebrew year, So :
Hope you'll have a good year and Happy holiday :P